# Can I declare props type for a functional UI component?

Tags: reactjs

In other words, can I do something like this with React + TypeScript or React + Flow?

```
function Foo(rect:Rect) {
   return <div><span>{rect.x}</span><span>{rect.y}</span></div>;
}
```

Instead of this:

```
function Foo({x,y}:{x:number,y:number}) {
   return <div><span>{x}</span><span>{y}</span></div>;
}
```

Comment: JavaScript is not a statically typed language, so really don't get what you mean?

Comment: you can use flow or typescript if you want to do something like that. Otherwise react has PropTypes natively https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html

Answer (score 1):

Create them as properties of your function. See https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#stateless-functions

```
function YourComponent(props) {}

YourComponent.propTypes = {
  someProp: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default YourComponent;
```

In Javascript functions are just objects.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer I was looking for:

```
// TypeScript
class Foo extends React.Component<FooProps, FooState> {}

// Flow
class Foo extends React.Component {
  state: FooState;
  props: FooProps;
}
```